# Uso de "mutate" y "ifelse" para convertir factores en valores numéricos

Tags: r

de entrada informar que he estado tratando de aprender R de forma autodidacta y tengo muchos vacíos en programación. Luego de la advertencia quisiera plantearles un problema: Estoy generando una nueva columna en un df a partir de los niveles que están contenidos en otra columna (en este caso P23). Para ello, uso la sintaxis siguiente:

```
df <- df%>%
    mutate(nueva_columna = ifelse(P23=="Ninguno", 1,
              ifelse(P23=="Centro de Alfabetización/(EBA)", 2,
                ifelse(P23=="Pre escolar", 3,
                  ifelse(P23=="Primario", 4,
                    ifelse(P23=="Secundario", 5, 99))))))
```

Así, los valores de la nueva_columna están predeterminados por los "niveles" de la columna original. EN algunos casos, las columnas originales pueden contener mas de 20 niveles diferentes y el trabajo es medio engorroso.

¿Hay otra forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la naturaleza del dato `Factor`, es muy sencillo transformarlos en un valor numérico:

```
df <- df%>%
    mutate(nueva_columna = as.integer(P23))
```

Claro que los valores numéricos son los índices con los que se creo el `factor`, si necesitaras un valor en particular, puede hacer una tabla de conversión:

```
valores_desados <- c(5, 12, 2, 4 ...)
df <- df%>%
    mutate(nueva_columna = valores_desados[as.integer(P23)])
```

Sino, y usando algo parecido a lo que has intentado, puedes aprovechar las función [`case_when()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
  nueva_columna  = case_when(P23 == "Ninguno" ~ 1,
                             P23 == "Centro de Alfabetización/(EBA)" ~ 2,
                             P23 == "Pre escolar" ~ 3),
                             P23 == "Primario" ~ 4),
                             P23 == "Secundario" ~ 5),
                             TRUE ~ 99
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, La primera opción no me está funcionado, porque creo que los valores de la columna a la que hago mención no tienen un orden adecuado y los valores de los factores no se corresponden con los valores de la etiqueta. No se si logro explicarme bien, voy con un poco más de detalle: Al parecer, lo que aparece como segundo nivel de mis factores no es "Centro de Alfabetización/EBA", sino "Secundario". Tu segundo opción me viene muy bien y estéticamente es mucho mejor que la combinación mutate / ifelse. Muchas gracias, me ayudaste un montón